# react doesnt work properly inside jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I am using jQuery steps in react

I have this in my render method

```
<div id='wizard-1'> <h1>First Step</h1> <div> <Ac_fieldContainer /> </div> <h1>Second Step</h1> <div>Information</div> </div>
```

and this in componentDidMount

```
    $('#wizard-1').steps({
       autoFocus: true
    });
```

Ac_fieldContainer is a react component in which I use react dnd plugin but
the drag and drop API doesn't work inside the jQuery steps
but it works perfectly at any other place.

I think it's because react doesn't behave good when other plugins manipulate the DOM, what can I do?

Comment: well there is going to be a conflict when you use two "view libraries". is your jQuery code in your `componentDidMount` lifecycle method?

Comment: Follow this guide https://github.com/ryanflorence/react-training/blob/gh-pages/lessons/05-wrapping-dom-libs.md

Comment: @bitten yes my jquery code in componentDidMount

Comment: @AndyRay thanks, i will follow the guide and see if it is gonna work